# Tomcat deployed war is not deploying on JBoss

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, jboss, pom.xml, war

I am working on `Spring MVC project`.
It was locally deployed on `Tomcat` server(apache-tomcat-7.0.85) correctly without any issue.
But my supervisor asked me to deploy it on `JBoss` server, because our company is using JBoss server in production level.
So, I tried to deploy it on JBoss server locally, But it's not working well.

My url (http://localhost:8080/MCloudServices-1.0/test) is giving 404 error.
The problem is no any error in server log.

Is there any version error or Am I have to do some configuration changers when moving Tomcat to JBoss? I search this on google but couldn't find any solution.
I'm new to to Spring MVC, Hoping a solution for this.

Tomcat version I used   --> apache-tomcat-7.0.85

JBoss versions I checked--> jboss-5.0.0.GA and jboss-6.1.0.Final

Spring version   --> 4.1.9.RELEASE

Also I have attached here with pom.xml and server.log

server.log

`===============================================================================                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   JBoss Bootstrap Environment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               JAVA_OPTS: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -server -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      CLASSPATH: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\bin\run.jar                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ===============================================================================                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0                                                                 10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...                                                                                                      10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [Morpheus] 5.0.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_0_0_GA date=200812041714)                                                  10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null                                                                                                                     10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA                                                                                                             10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/                                                                                                      10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/lib/                                                                                               10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null                                                                                                                         10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/common/                                                                                        10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/common/lib/                                                                                 10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default                                                                                                                    10:02:21,850 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server                                                                                               10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/                                                                                        10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/conf/                                                                         10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default                                                                                       10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/                                                                                10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\data                                                                                  10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/lib/                                                                         10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\log                                                                                    10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\tmp\native                                                                          10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\tmp                                                                                   10:02:21,865 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\tmp\deploy                                                                     10:02:22,214 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml                                         10:02:22,487 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.IterableTimedVFSCache]                                                      10:02:22,487 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [IterableTimedVFSCache{lifetime=1800, resolution=60}]                                                               10:02:22,643 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server\default\tmp                                                                                   10:02:22,643 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.                                                                                        10:02:23,574 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.8.0_144,Oracle Corporation                                                                                              10:02:23,574 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.144-b01,Oracle Corporation                                                                10:02:23,574 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 10 10.0,amd64                                                                                                        10:02:23,590 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized                                                                                                              10:02:24,973 INFO  [ProfileServiceImpl] Loading profile: default from: org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.SerializableDeploymentRepository@61842590(root=C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server, key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default])                                             10:02:24,973 INFO  [ProfileImpl] Using repository:org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.SerializableDeploymentRepository@61842590(root=C:\jboss-5.0.0.GA\server, key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default])                                                                  10:02:24,973 INFO  [ProfileServiceImpl] Loaded profile: ProfileImpl@1619ca3d{key=org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileKey@143b82c3[domain=default,server=default,name=default]}                                                                                                                                                                  10:02:29,452 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/                                                                                       10:02:33,786 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core                                                                                          10:02:33,786 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.0.4.SP1                                                                                                                       10:02:44,016 INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/jmxconnector                                 10:05:46,163 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail                                                                                                       10:05:47,141 WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this.           10:05:47,141 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent                                        10:05:47,251 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version) - JBoss Inc.                                                                   10:05:47,251 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer                                                                          10:05:47,440 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager                                                                                            10:05:47,520 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager configured                                                                                              10:05:47,521 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference                                                                                10:05:47,546 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting transaction recovery manager                                                                                    10:05:47,952 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080                                                                                 10:05:47,952 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009                                                                                      10:05:47,952 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web                                                                                                         10:05:47,952 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBoss Web/2.1.1.GA                                                                                         10:05:47,968 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 58 ms                                                                                                                   10:05:47,984 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console, vfsUrl=management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war                                                   10:05:48,958 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws, vfsUrl=jbossws.sar/jbossws-management.war                                                               10:05:48,989 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker, vfsUrl=http-invoker.sar/invoker.war                                                                     10:05:49,228 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml              10:05:49,321 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml                 10:05:49,384 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jms-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml                        10:05:49,531 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/mail-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml                       10:05:49,594 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml                     10:05:49,672 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main                                                                       10:05:49,688 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.                                                                                                  10:05:49,688 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.                                                                                                               10:05:49,688 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'        10:05:49,688 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2                                                                                                10:05:49,688 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.                                                                          10:05:50,047 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'         10:05:50,464 WARN  [QuartzTimerServiceFactory] sql failed: CREATE TABLE QRTZ_JOB_DETAILS(JOB_NAME VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, JOB_GROUP VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(120) NULL, JOB_CLASS_NAME VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, IS_DURABLE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, IS_VOLATILE VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, IS_STATEFUL VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, REQUESTS_RECOVERY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, JOB_DATA BINARY NULL, PRIMARY KEY (JOB_NAME,JOB_GROUP))                                                                                           10:05:50,480 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main                                                                       10:05:50,480 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.                                                                                                  10:05:50,480 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).                                                                            10:05:50,480 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 Volatile Trigger(s).                                                                                                         10:05:50,480 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 Volatile Job(s).                                                                                                             10:05:50,480 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] JobStoreCMT initialized.                                                                                                               10:05:50,480 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'JBossEJB3QuartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.                       10:05:50,495 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2                                                                                                10:05:50,495 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Freed 0 triggers from 'acquired' / 'blocked' state.                                                                                    10:05:50,495 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Recovering 0 jobs that were in-progress at the time of the last shut-down.                                                             10:05:50,495 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Recovery complete.                                                                                                                     10:05:50,495 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 'complete' triggers.                                                                                                         10:05:50,495 INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 stale fired job entries.                                                                                                     10:05:50,495 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler JBossEJB3QuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.                                                                        10:05:50,707 INFO  [ServerPeer] JBoss Messaging 1.4.1.GA server [0] started                                                                                             10:05:50,754 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/DLQ] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000                                                         10:05:50,769 WARN  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsFailover attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory will *not* support failover                                                                             10:05:50,769 WARN  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsLoadBalancing attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory will *not* support load balancing                                                                  10:05:50,801 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds                                         10:05:50,801 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@cbd98e3 started                                                         10:05:50,801 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds                                         10:05:50,801 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@2d3a34ff started                                                        10:05:50,801 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/ExpiryQueue] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000                                                 10:05:50,801 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds                                         10:05:50,801 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@21fff299 started                                                        10:05:50,847 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'          10:05:52,424 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/MCloudServices-1.0, vfsUrl=MCloudServices-1.0.war                                                                10:05:52,492 WARN  [config] Unable to process deployment descriptor for context '/MCloudServices-1.0'                                                                   10:05:52,795 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/, vfsUrl=ROOT.war                                                                                                10:05:52,888 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console, vfsUrl=jmx-console.war                                                                              10:05:52,942 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080                                                                                     10:05:52,952 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009                                                                                          10:05:52,983 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.0.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_0_0_GA date=200812041714)] Started in 3m:31s:118ms`

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MCloudServices</groupId>
  <artifactId>MCloudServices</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.1.9.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.0.4</mysql.connector.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>                         
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>   
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Am I need to change the web.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `jboss-web.xml` under your `WEB-INF` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>yourWebappContextRoot</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```